# Real-time notifications using Laravel Livewire

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, frontend, laravel-livewire

Specifically, I am trying to alert a user when he/she has a message.

The problem is that once a message is sent, the inbox count does not update until I reload the page.

I want to Update the view with real-time data from the back-end. What do I do?

This is my wire view:
[image]

This is my wire-component:
[image]

PS: to test this, I've implemented an increment method and it works upon clicking. Same can't be said for unreadCount(). I am new to livewire so, any help rendered will be appreciated

Comment: Please read - How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please share the formatted code, and not screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an easy task, but I hope I can help you.

Basically, there are two ways to resolve this.

The first one is using [Livewire Polling](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling), where your frontend requests the database every 2 seconds to check if there are any new notifications for this user. Specifically, you can use wire:poll.keep-alive in your case.

```
<div class="{{$this->unreadCount > 0 ? 'block' : 'hidden'}}"
     wire:poll.keep-alive>
    You have {{$this->unreadCount}} new notifications.
</div>
```

It is important to clarify that, depending on the size of your project and the number of users, **this solution may overload your database with frequent requests.**

In advance, you can use a [WebSocket](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting) solution, which is the second and ideal approach. It acts as a monitor that checks your backend application and only sends the unreadCount to your frontend when an [event](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events) is emitted.

The difference between the two approaches is that the first one makes **requests** to the **database every 2 seconds**, while the second one **only does when the event is emitted**.

It's worth to know that the WebSocket solution is more complex and requires knowledge of Laravel [events and listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events). However, there are plenty of [online resources available](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUlbN_xsdXg&pp=ygUYaG93IHRvIHdlYnNvY2tldCBsYXJhdmVs&ab_channel=Acadea.io) about WebSockets. If you are comfortable with these concepts and pretend to scale your application, you can give it a try.

There are free WebSocket solutions, but I recommend you to go with [Pusher](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels) because the Laravel App is already pre-configured for use it. Using pusher, you have a free plan that receives until 200k messages per day and 100 connections that is just nice for small projects.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, The live-wire poll worked like magic thanks. I tried web-socket however, it only works for php 7.1 idk. I might use pusher in the future.

Comment: Hey! That's so nice to hear. About websocket, are you using a previous PHP version? And yeah, develop this solution probably deserves a project for thinking exactly on how to complete this task. I believe that some YouTube content may be useful.

Comment: Curious how this works with livewire, though. How are you listening for pusher events to a subscriber and having livewire update?